# Toggle new li and still count the last ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got these `<img>` tags which all have unique values. Some of them are displayed on a different `<div>` which I toggle.

As you can see when I press on the toggled `<div>`s `<img>`s the count starts over again. I tried to `val('')` the `<img>`s on toggle which works but I would like to be able to see them in the background.

Is there anything I could add to my code without removing `var img_id = $(this).closest('li').index();` to make the code consider all `<li>` tags?

```js
$("#yy").click(function(){
  $("#why").fadeToggle(250);
  $("#tts").css("display", "none");
});
    
$(".iq").on('click', '[data-video]', function(){
  var img_id = $(this).closest('li').index();
  alert(img_id);
});
```

```css
#why{
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  height:50%;
  background-color:rgba(79, 79, 90, 0.92);
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
#yy{
  background-color:black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "searchBarN" class = "iq">
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="one" alt="play"> </li><br>
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="2"  alt="play"> </li><br>
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="3"  alt="play"> </li><br>            
</div>

<div id = "why" class = "iq">
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="4"  alt="play"> </li><br>
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="5"  alt="play"> </li>  <br> 
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="6"  alt="play"> </li><br>
</div>

<div id = "yy"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidenote: I think you shouldn't use `index()`, as this takes `<br>` into account, and all additional tags you may add later (this is why you're seeing 0/2/4 instead of 0/1/2). Instead, you'd better use `attr('data-video')`, but this depends on your needs.

---

I don't understand what you' trying to achieve with this code, but without changing everything my first guess would be to detect if you clicked on a `#why` child, and if so add the number of `#searchBarN` direct children to your index:

```js
$("#yy").click(function(){
  $("#why").fadeToggle(250);
  $("#tts").css("display", "none");
});

$(".iq").on('click', '[data-video]', function(){
  var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
  if ($(this).parents('#why').length) {
    index += $('#searchBarN > *').length;
  }
  alert(index);
});
```

```css
#why{
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  height:50%;
  background-color:rgba(79, 79, 90, 0.92);
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
#yy{
  background-color:black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "searchBarN" class = "iq">
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="one" alt="play"> </li><br>
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="2"  alt="play"> </li><br>
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="3"  alt="play"> </li><br>            
</div>

<div id = "why" class = "iq">
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="4"  alt="play"> </li><br>
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="5"  alt="play"> </li>  <br> 
  <li class="rutor"><img data-video="6"  alt="play"> </li><br>
</div>

<div id = "yy"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know how to write it but you guessed correctly I wanted to add the searchBarN children to my index. I dont normaly use br tags it was just to make it look a little better.